# How do I load data from the mysql after clicking the submit button?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to create a PHP page wherein once the submit button is clicked the the data will be inserted into the database, and it will show all the data from the database without refresh. Is that possible?

I have a separate PHP file which contains the SQL `INSERT` statement and the `SELECT` statement that will retreive the data.

I'm trying to achieve this using the post method of the form.

Comment: Q: Is that possible? A: Yes. :)

Comment: Google it before u post a question.

Answer (score 1):

On the form, give the `action=` attribute to the insertion page:

```
<form action='insert.php' method='post'>
```

On the insertion page, redirect the page to the data selection page by using a header:

```
header('Location: select.php');
```

Then it will execute that data on the insertion page and directly go to the selection page.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible. you need to use the ajax that will do all the thing without refreshing the page. below links will be helpful to understand the process.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/